# Neo4J Cypher: Why is assigning nodes to variables required in the shortestPath function

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, shortest-path

When I try to execute a `shortestPath()` function between a `Person` node and a `Movie` node, like -

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((:Person)-[*1..4]->(:Movie))
RETURN length(p)
```

This fails with the error -

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
shortestPath(...) requires named nodes (line 1, column 9 (offset: 8))
"MATCH p=shortestPath((:Person)-[*1..4]->(:Movie))"
         ^
```

To fix this, I must assign the node labels to variables, like so -

```
MATCH pt=shortestPath((p:Person)-[*1..4]->(m:Movie))
RETURN length(pt)
```

This produces the correct return -

```
length(pt)
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
3
```

and so on.

Why is this required? I'm not using the variables `p` or `m` anywhere in my `RETURN` clause.

I couldn't find an explanation in the `shortestPath()` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed your question to the team during the open cypher meeting in Monday, on this is the answer :

> There is no need for those variables any more. there might have been
>   in the past, and the check remains for legacy reasons. it's a fair
>   feature request.

Cheers

Comment: But I executed this query with the latest version of Neo4J (`3.3.0)`, and it still threw this error. In fact, I was using the "Neo4J Desktop" release, which came out just a few weeks back, so it is the latest.

Comment: You have right, you still have to define the start & ending node for the shortestpath (even on a 3.3), but like you observe, there is no need to have them. It's a legacy problematic ...